# What are the rules about calling PHP functions with not enough parameters?

Tags: php, parameters, arguments, optional-parameters

I have a function which takes two arguments but I want the second one to be optional:

```
function myFunction($arg1, $arg2) {
  //blah
  //blah
  if (isset($arg2)) {
    //blah
  } else {
    //blah
  }
}
```

So when I call it, I might do `myFunction("something")` or I might do `myFunction("something", "something else")`.

When I only include one argument, PHP gives this warning:

> Warning: Missing argument 2 for myFunction(), ...

So it works, but obviously the developers frown upon it.

Is it ok to do this or should I be passing in `""` or `false` or `0` to the second argument when I don't want to use it and testing for that instead of using `isset()`?

I've noticed that a lot of people miss out arguments when calling functions in JavaScript which is why I'm asking if it's done in PHP too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its done by setting up some parameters as optional/giving it a default:

```
function myFunction($arg1, $arg2 = false)
```

then you can call the function like this:

`myFunction('something');`

or

`myFunction('something', 'something else');`

Answer (score 3):

You can set it in your function declaration:

```
function myFunction($arg1, $arg2 = NULL) {
```

This way, the second parameter is optional. Note that the optional parameters have to be at the end, you cannot have any non-optional parameters after them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a default for the argument in the function declaration, like this:

```
function myFunction($arg1, $arg2 = false) {
  //blah
  //blah
  if (isset($arg2)) {
    //blah
  } else {
    //blah
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

function myFunction($arg1, $arg2=null)

http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default

Answer (score 0):

Define a default value of the parameter in the function:

```
public function foo($arg1, $arg2 = 'default') {
    //yourfunction 
}
```